# Many to Many Table SQL Selection Problem

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have two tables that are related, which, for the purpose of this question, will be called `posts` and `tags`. `posts` contains various postings, such as those found on a community forum system. `tags` contains a unique set of tags, that are added when the server encounters a new tag that is not already in the system. There is only one entry per tag.

`posts` can have multiple tags, and `tags` can have more than one post that is a reference to it. To handle these references back and forth, I have created a table to sit in between these two tables, called `posttags`. `posttags` contains a reference to the `tag` id and the `post` id. This is how the many to many relationship is maintained.

Now, on to the problem. I need to be able to select posts based on a tag. This is a simple join when there is only one tag to search for, but I am at a loss as to how to handle multiple tags. For instance, I need to be able to search the database and get results that have ALL of the tags that are in a list (e.g., "php, mysql, sql"), without using SQL inside of a loop or any other low performance options.

I am not sure how to do this. Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following approach, 3 is quantity of requested tags.

```
SELECT PostId
FROM posttags pt, tags t
WHERE p.Id = pt.PostId
  AND t.Id = pt.TagId
  AND tagname In ('php', 'mysql', 'sql')
group by PostId
having count(*) = 3
```

or you can sort you requested tags join them in order and use the following:

```
Select * from Posts p,
(  
 SELECT PostId, GROUP_CONCAT(tagname ORDER BY tag_name DESC SEPARATOR ' ') Tags
 FROM posttags pt, tags t
 WHERE p.Id = pt.PostId
   AND t.Id = pt.TagId
 GROUP BY PostId
```

) t
   WHERE t.PostId = p.Id
     AND t.Tags = 'mysql php sql'

But you need sort your tags

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the posts which have *all* tags in a given set, you can use a "counting" strategy:

```
SELECT
  p.*
FROM tags t
LEFT JOIN posttags pt
  ON pt.tag_id = t.tag_id
LEFT JOIN posts p
  ON p.post_id = pt.post_id
WHERE
  tags.tag IN ('php', 'mysql', 'sql')
GROUP BY p.post_id
HAVING COUNT(tags.tag_id) = 3;
```

Of course, if you change the set, the number "3" should be changed to the number of elements in the set.

Comment: Great answer. Both you and Micheal answered the same type of thing, so I had to give the correct answer to Micheal since he answered first. However, thanks for explaining what the query did!